# How to replace sublists with NIL in Lisp?

Tags: list, common-lisp

I have a project in Common Lisp and I need help.

I have for example the list:

```lisp
(( C ) ( A C ) (  ) (  ) ( P B ) (  ) ( C C A ) ( A ))
```

and I want to replace all the sublists except the sublist which contains the element `P`. There's only one `P` in the whole list and it's always the first element in a sublist. So the result should be:

```lisp
(NIL NIL NIL NIL ( P B ) NIL NIL NIL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem combines mapping and membership testing.  Both of these functionalities are available in common lisp:

```lisp
(mapcar (lambda (list) (member 'p list))
         '((c) (a c) () () (p b) (c c a) (a)))

;; (NIL NIL NIL NIL (P B) NIL NIL)
```

More documentation on mapping can be found in the [hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm)

We could also use iteration:

```lisp
(loop for item in '((c) (a c) () () (p b) (c c a) (a))
          collect (member 'p item))
;; (NIL NIL NIL NIL (P B) NIL NIL)
```